Not getting Logs in structured key value pair format
I am pushing the application logs from EKS cluster to Loki, using flunetbit, i am able to get the logs , but the dev team want that the logs should be in structured key value pair format.
2024-09-02T11:04:05.246209498-04:00 stdout F {"timestamp":"2024-09-02T15:04:05.246Z","sequence":27568,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"org.jgroups.protocols.TCP","level":"WARN","message":"JGRP000032: deployment-keycloak-694b65969c-gfv92-18194: no physical address for deployment-keycloak-694b65969c-mjgvr-42926, dropping message","threadName":"TQ-Bundler-7,deployment-keycloak-694b65969c-gfv92-18194","threadId":30,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"deployment-keycloak-694b65969c-gfv92","processName":"QuarkusEntryPoint","processId":1}
it should be like this
    labels: - source - level - threadName - threadId - hostName - sourceClassName - sourceFileName - sourceMethodName - sourceLineNumber
Below is my flunetbit code
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-config
  namespace: pds-logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluent-bit
data:
  parsers.conf: |-
    [PARSER]
        Name        json
        Format      json 
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L

  custom_parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name docker_no_time
        Format json
        Time_Keep Off
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L

  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush 10
        Daemon Off
        Log_Level info
        storage.sync normal
        storage.checksum Off
        storage.max_chunks_up 550
        storage.backlog.mem_limit 100M
        buffer.flush 1m
        buffer.chunk_size 256KB
        Buffer_Max_Size 512KB      
        Parsers_File parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server On
        HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port 2020

    [INPUT]
        Name tail               
        Exclude_Path /var/log/containers/*_kube-system_*,/var/log/containers/*_torq-system_*,/var/log/containers/*_datadog_*,/var/log/containers/*_pds-cnnfr-schema-registry_*,/var/log/containers/*_pds-cnnfr-test_*,/var/log/containers/*_stackrox_*,/var/log/containers/*_chaos-testing_*,/var/log/containers/*_istio-upgrade-validation_*,/var/log/containers/*_kube-node-lease_*,/var/log/containers/*_kube-public_*,/var/log/containers/*_pds-cnnfr-keycloak_*,/var/log/containers/*_pds-cnnfr-schema-registry_*,/var/log/containers/*_pds-cnnfr-schema-registry_*,/var/log/containers/*_istio-system_*,/var/log/containers/*_pds-logging_*,/var/log/containers/*_pds-cnnfr-east1a-testbed_*,/var/log/containers/*_wiz_*,/var/log/containers/*_prometheus_*
        Path /var/log/containers/*_pds-cnnfr-mrc_*.log
        Parser json
        Tag kube.*
        Mem_Buf_Limit 5000MB
        Refresh_Interval 5 
        Skip_Long_Lines On
        

    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Kube_Tag_Prefix kube.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log On
        Labels On
        Annotations On
        Buffer_Size 256KB
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On
        Keep_Log Off

    [OUTPUT]
        Name loki
        Match kube.*
        Host  loki-nfr.pds.dev.use.torq.dev
        Port  443
        TLS   On
        TLS.Verify off
        labels job=fluentbit, stream=$kubernetes['container_name'], namespace_name=$kubernetes['namespace_name'], pod=$kubernetes['pod_name'], container_image=$kubernetes['container_image'], pod_name=$kubernetes['pod_name'], pod_id=$kubernetes['pod_id']
        line_format json
        auto_kubernetes_labels on
    
    [OUTPUT]
        Name es
        Match kube.*
        Host  10.90.45.116
        Port  9200
        Index pds-cnnfr-use1
        Retry_Limit 5
        Time_Key @timestamp
        Buffer_Size 20000MB
        Trace_Output off

Can someone please help here, i am stuck in this for weeks, but no luck as of now
I tried using diffrent aprser but dint worked out.

Can someone please help here
